# SDL2 Message Box not showing colors, parent does not work

Tags: windows, colors, parent, sdl-2, messagebox

```
SDL_Window* mainWindow = NULL;

void cleanup();

const SDL_MessageBoxButtonData msgBox_CloseWindow_Buttons [] = {
    {0, 0, "Nope"},
    {SDL_MESSAGEBOX_BUTTON_RETURNKEY_DEFAULT, 1, "Yup"},
    {SDL_MESSAGEBOX_BUTTON_ESCAPEKEY_DEFAULT, 2, "Cancel it"},
};

const SDL_MessageBoxColorScheme msgBox_CloseWindow_ColorScheme = {
    {
        // SDL_MESSAGEBOX_COLOR_BACKGROUND
        {255, 0, 0},
        // SDL_MESSAGEBOX_COLOR_TEXT
        {0, 255, 0},
        // SDL_MESSAGEBOX_COLOR_BUTTON_BORDER
        {255, 255, 0},
        // SDL_MESSAGEBOX_COLOR_BUTTON_BACKGROUND
        {0, 0, 255},
        // SDL_MESSAGEBOX_COLOR_BUTTON_SELECTED
        {255, 0, 255}
    }
};
const SDL_MessageBoxData msgBox_CloseWindow_Data = {
    // flag
    SDL_MESSAGEBOX_INFORMATION,
    // window
    mainWindow,
    // title
    "Game Terminating",
    // message
    "Do you really want to close this way?",
    // number of buttons
    SDL_arraysize(msgBox_CloseWindow_Buttons),
    msgBox_CloseWindow_Buttons,
    &msgBox_CloseWindow_ColorScheme
};

void closeWindowMessageBox()
{
    if(SDL_ShowMessageBox(&msgBox_CloseWindow_Data, &nbutton) < 0)
    {
        SDL_Log("error displaying box");
        exit(1);
    }
    switch (nbutton)
    {
        case -1:
            SDL_Log("Game Closing - No Selection");
            break;
        case 0:
            SDL_Log("Game Closing - Rejected");
            break;
        case 1:
            SDL_Log("Game Closing - Approved");
            cleanup();
            break;
        case 2:
            SDL_Log("Game Closing - Canceled");
            break;
    }
}

void Game::ProcessEvents(SDL_Event event)
{
    switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
    {
        ...
    }
    switch(event.type)
    {
        case SDL_QUIT:
                closeWindowMessageBox();
                break;
    }
}
```

However, The message box is with no colors
It's likely no parent too (Not on the top of the main window)
Shouldn't it prevent me from clicking on the parent, I mean like a Dialog Box in **.NET**
What's the meaning of a parent window in **SDL** anyways?

[image: Windows SDL2 MessageBox with no parent]

*As you can see*, I **minimized** the game from the game window (message box **did not** prevent me)
and this **gray** message box is **not**, it's just somewhere on the screen alone with no parent to hold it.

I'm working on the latest **SDL2**, using a **parent** or **colors** is like setting them to `NULL`.

I even tried copying the whole example from the [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_ShowMessageBox) and replacing all the `closeWindowMessageBox()` function with it, except the parent, replaced with **mainWindow**.

**Well**, now the parent worked (prevents other events from occurring until I click a button).
[image]

I think cause I needed to **initialize** the **mainWindow** first
`closeWindowMessageBox()` is called after the initialization of `mainWindow` so it worked

the difference is that when defining them in the header it'd take the current value of `mainWindow` which is `NULL`, hope it helps if someone had the same problem.

**Still no colors**, What do I missed?, thanks.

Comment: Colour schemes only supported on x11 and android. As for parent, your example in question sure sets it to NULL.

Comment: So I conclude its better to set the color scheme to `NULL` in **windows** unless If I want it portable, thanks for the info. ++;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color schemes features aren't available in **Windows**, or at least for now.

Comment: Do you know if that's also the reason why I am not getting the icons?

Comment: I didn't try that but if it's not possible so I've 2 solutions for you, You can either use Qt (It supports color schemes for almost everything in a pretty easy HTML/CSS way). If your goal is just to create an OpenGL Context with SDL2 like me, you can code your own Messagebox system (Drawing Texts/Rectangles with event handling i.e `switch case`) which is quite easy if you're experienced with OpenGL and you can use a library if you want. The only disadvantage of the 2nd solution is that all msgboxes would be in the parent. Not a problem if your goal is just to use the Context.